# B4ABridge not working for most of files

Tags: basic4android

I am trying several examples from the forum, most of the samples are not in my phone but are unable to be installed via the B4ABridge even it says it is connected. How can this be fixed?

this is what it says:
*Installing file to device.              0.20
    Installing with B4A-Bridge.
Installation will fail if the signing key is different than the previous used key.
In that case you will need to manually uninstall the existing application.
Completed successfully.*

regards

Comment: The message you copied here indicates that the install worked.

Comment: Hi, I have worked with the B4ABridge, it just seems with some apps works with other not..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if other features work. For example, can you see the logs?
Make sure that you allowed installation of non-market applications.

Comment: Thanks Erel, Even I have message of connected have experienced this issues, I had several instances of B4A running with several code, I close all an start with only my project and now is working so Guess I have to have one open at a time.